# Encode integer sequence to smallest string php

Tags: php, encoding

I have a long sequence of numbers, their all lower than 5 and I want to encode it to a string to reduce string length as much as I can, but maintain the ability to retrive the original one.

I thought of change to higher base:

```
<?php
$str = '2222342022223411112203302222232222122221230222';
$baseEncodeFrom = 5;
$baseEncodeTo = 36;
echo base_convert(base_convert($str,$baseEncodeFrom,$baseEncodeTo),$baseEncodeTo,$baseEncodeFrom);
//2222342022223411112203413300041330121304332023
```

But, as mentioned in php reference, with big numbers you lose precision, hence you lose the original string. Is there a way to reduce the original string length and still be able to retrive the original one?

Comment: Silly question perhaps but what is the reason you want to reduce the string length?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look in to different compression methods and algorithms, because how far you can compress will depend on the algorithm. For example, here's an incredibly naive naive and probably inefficient algorithm.

```
<?php

$str = '2222342022223411112203302222232222122221230222';
echo $str . "\r\n";

$values = [

];

$lastChar = null;
$value = [];
foreach (str_split($str) as $character) {
    if ($lastChar === null) {
        $value = ['number' => $character, 'count' => 1];
        $lastChar = $character;
        continue;
    }

    if ($lastChar !== $character) {
        $values[] = $value;
        $value = ['number' => $character, 'count' => 0];
    }

    $value['count']++;
    $lastChar = $character;
}

$values[] = $value;

function combine($a, $b) {
    return str_pad(base_convert($a, 10, 2), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . str_pad(base_convert($b, 10, 2), 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

function compressValue($value) {
    $return = '';

    if ($value['count'] > 8) {
        $return .= compressValue(['number' => $value['number'], 'count' => $value['count'] - 8]);
        $value['count'] = $value['count'] % 8;
    }

    $return .= combine($value['count'], $value['number']);

    return $return;
};

$values = array_map('compressValue', $values);
$values = join("", $values);
$values = str_split($values, 8);
$values = array_map(function ($value) {
    $ord = chr(bindec($value));
    return $ord;
}, $values);
$values = join("", $values);
echo $values . "\r\n";

echo strlen($values) . "\r\n";
echo strlen($str) . "\r\n";
```

Which outputs... a lot of unreadable characters. That has a strlen of 23! Shorter than the original of 46!

So what does it do? It takes the string, and says "There's 4 2's, followed by 1x3, 1x4, 1x2 1x0, 4x2" and so on. Then it takes those and turns them in to a combined binary. We'll make each 8-bit binary be one length of letters. So 4x2 because 00100 . 010 Since all numbers are below 5, we're using the last 3 digits of the binary for the number, and the other 5 for the count. If there's more than 31 (The max count we can store in 5 bits), we'll just store the rest in the next byte.

Then, we have a long string of binary, so we convert it to hexedecimal.

So, to convert back, we could just convert from hex to binary, then split that in to chunks of 8 digits, and take the first 5 of each chunk, convert it to dec and take the next 3 of the chunk, convert it to dec and then repeat the second dec by the amount of times in the first dec

That being said, this is just my first attempt at a compression algorithm, and I don't know much about them. So if you Google'd to find out more information, and research in to different algorithms you could probably find much more effecient ways of doing it. There are probably also bugs in my program, it's a short proof of concept

The code to decode it is

```
$values = str_split($values);
$values = array_map(function ($value) {
    return str_pad(decbin(ord($value)), 8, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}, $values);

$values = array_map(function ($value) {
    $count = substr($value, 0, 5);
    $number = substr($value, 5, 3);

    $count = base_convert($count, 2, 10);
    $number = base_convert($number, 2, 10);

    return str_repeat($number, $count);
}, $values);

echo join("", $values);
```